# Geotools Point to Text with srid

Tags: java, geotools

Can I convert a geometry point to wkt including the srid formatted. See below the example.

"SRID=4326;POINT(-43.9725637435913 -19.9411078674228)".

Although I tried to put point.toText() only return the coordinate without the srid.

Comment: You do not have WKT but enhanced PostGIS variant "EWKT". There seems to be something for that, for example https://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/2.7-M2-GS/modules/plugin/postgis/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/postgis/attributeio/EWKTAttributeIO.java.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (currently) read [EWKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text#Variations) directly - the simplest route is to split the string at `;` and handle the two parts.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    WKTReader2 reader = new WKTReader2();
    String line = "";
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
      try {
        Geometry g;
        if(line.contains(";")) {
           String[] parts = line.split(";");
           CRS.decode("EPSG:"+parts[0].substring(5));
            g = reader.read(parts[1]);   
        } else {
          g = reader.read(line);
        }

        System.out.println("\t"+g);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("invalid input");
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

  }

}
```

If you want to write EWKT out then you need to look up (and probably cache) the EPSG code from your projection object.

```
Point p = GenerateRandomData.createRandomPoint();
CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append("SRID=");

buffer.append(CRS.lookupEpsgCode(crs, false)).append(';');
WKTWriter2 writer = new WKTWriter2();
buffer.append(writer.write(p));

System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Comment: With JTS VividSolutions is the same way , isn't it ?

Comment: Point p is a JTS Point